# Alternate wine install needs deletion

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wine

I'm running into a strange issue where I have two working wine installs.  This one is stumping me.

I'm using Centos version 5.6.

The legacy wine was installed via `rpm` or `yum`; I'm not sure which. `yum uninstall wine` was run and succeeded, yet wine version 1.0 still exists.

The new wine version was compiled from source

`which wine` as a normal user gives this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/wine
```

`wine --version` as a normal user gives this output:

```
wine-1.0.1
```

... as root, `which wine` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/wine
```

and `wine --version` gives:

```
wine-1.3.21
```

`find / -name wine` gives:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/wine
/usr/lib/wine
/usr/bin/wine
/usr/share/wine
/usr/local/lib/wine
/usr/local/bin/wine
/usr/local/share/wine
/usr/local/include/wine
```

The legacy wine version is in `/usr/`.

Anyway, how can I uninstall the legacy version completely?

Comment: What package manager did you use to install wine?

Comment: i believe the legacy version of wine was installed via yum. forgot to mention that im running centos 5.6... new version was compiled from source

Answer (score 1):

You should run (as both a normal user and as root):

```
/usr/bin/wine --version
/usr/local/bin/wine --version
```

It would appear that `which` is confused about which version of `wine` is run by one of the two users, most likely `root`.  This might be because one of the shells has an alias for `wine` which `which` is unaware of, or something similar.

As to uninstalling the system `wine` - if you can't get it removed with `yum`, then I'd simply make sure that my PATH runs the preferred version.  Depending on circumstances (mainly how many concurrent versions of a given piece of software I expect to install), I will create my own version for install in `/usr/gnu` or `$HOME/Software/Product/vN.NN` or something similar, and make sure that the relevant `bin` directory is on my PATH ahead of the system directories.  I have 11 versions of Perl (from 5.6.2 to 5.14.0) installed in `$HOME/Perl/vN.NN.N` directories, for example.  (And I never modify the system Perl.  I doubt if 'the system' uses `wine`, but I don't know what would break if I modified the system's copy of Perl, so I simply don't take the risk.)

Comment: Thats more of a hack around than I was looking for. I was aware that is an option. I'm really hoping someone actually has a solution to a clean uninstall of this version of wine.. its a work computer. thanks for the input though

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was indeed also a hack around. did not delete wine however it "fixed" the issue easier than changing paths.

I created a symbolic link linking the 1.3 wine to the 1.0 executable and which is no longer having issues.

would love to have an ACTUAL solution though